# Can we do something to help those in need of urgent help?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, meta-tags

Via [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537269/define-a-positive-number-to-be-isolated-if-none-of-the-digits-in-its-square-are-i), I have discovered that SO has 13 questions tagged [`urgent-help-needed`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/urgent-help-needed). Most of these question do not have accepted answers!

That is horrific! We really should do something to prioritize questions marked urgent, as someone might just get fired or thrown out of school otherwise. Therefore, I propose that all questions with the [`urgent-help-needed`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/urgent-help-needed) tag is shown on the front page with an extra large, extra bold, Comic Sans font.

Also, a free bounty of 1000 rep. should automatically be attached to question with this tag.

<sub>Btw. I need help from a removing all occurences of a specific tag on SO. Can anyone help? This is urgent!</sub>

Comment: +1 hahahahaha... so ... this should be tagged *[retag-request]*, then?

Comment: Just one thing, when retagging, take the time to clean up the post too.

Comment: @voyager: hope you aren't asking for *this* post to be cleaned up, it's beautiful!  i wish all retag-requests were this ... *creative*.

Comment: Nice!  I wasn't sure if this was a joke or not all the way until "shown on the front page with an extra large, extra bold, Comic Sans font."

Comment: I totally lol'ed. This is EXACTLY what we need to do with such questions! Genius plan Jørn!

Comment: Some other people are not expert enough to have added that task, but have clearly stated the urgency of their question by writing "URGENT" (sometimes even in capital letters, to express extra urgency) in its title. We should help these people, too.

Comment: Too late to edit, but I was meaning "to have added that _tag_".

Comment: Is urgent-help-needed a meta tag?

Comment: *"We really should do something to prioritize questions marked urgent, as someone might just get fired or thrown out of school otherwise"* hahahaha :-)) *"... Also, a free bounty of 1000 rep. ..."* Are you for real? Didn't you forgot to add `[fun]` tag to this question?

Comment: No blinking? -1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are [none left now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/urgent-help-needed) (<s>the 4 questions left right now in that view are old cached copies, and will disappear shortly, along with the tag</s> - all gone!).

Comment: oh, I misread the revision history, I apologize :P

Comment: @Kop - no apology needed :-)

Answer (score 6):

> I propose that all questions with the urgent-help-needed  tag is shown on the front page with an extra large, extra bold, Comic Sans font.
>
> Also, a free bounty of 1000 rep. should automatically be attached to question with this tag.

I quite agree with this, but it would have be a purchasable question upgrade for the person asking the question (if they are in dire need, they surely can demonstrate such urgency financially) AND it would only be bolded/highlighted and with the bounty available for those who elect to participate in such questions by paying a small fee to SO for the privilege of helping those poor souls with urgent questions.

To everyone else, though, it would appear exactly as a regular question with no particular highlighting, and they would be ineligible for the 1k bounty.

As an aside, I'd like to invest in SO before this <strike>scheme</strike> feature is implemented.

Comment: For only a low monthly fee of $19.99, I'll tag *all* your questions with [urgent-help-needed].

Answer (score 4):

The more annoying tags, the better people can use them for filtering!

Answer (score 0):

The tags shouldn't be removed until their answer gets 2012 upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

A tooltip should appear recommending the asker remove [urgent-help-needed] once they have accepted an answer. The asker of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191666/how-to-stop-databasemail-from-executing) has forgotten to do so.